# keystoneclient.middleware.auth_token [-] Configuring auth_uri to point to the public identity endpoint is required

Tags: 12.04, openstack

I have installed OpenStack following the tutorial from

`http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/` in a single machine. It is installed successfully.

Now I am trying to install `Savanna` on `OpenStack`, following from

`https://savanna.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userdoc/installation.guide.html`

I have successfully completed

```
Step 5: -  savanna-venv/bin/python savanna-venv/bin/savanna-db-manage --config-file savanna-venv/etc/savanna.conf upgrade head
```

But when I Start Savanna Call

```
savanna-venv/bin/python savanna-venv/bin/savanna-api --config-file savanna-venv/etc/savanna.conf
```

I get this error, any solution?

```
WARNING keystoneclient.middleware.auth_token [-] 
Configuring auth_uri to point to the public identity endpoint is required;
clients may not be able to authenticate against an admin endpoint (23206) wsgi starting up on       http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

Answer (score 1):

That is just a warning. I think I saw that one on my setup and Savanna worked just fine. Try to run some queries agains the Savanna, see if they work.

Comment: It does not work at all.

Comment: Did you see some messages like   no previously-included directories found matching *  or similar when installing Savanna? I searched everywhere but found nothing helpful?
Can you guide me through installing Savanna?

Comment: Umair, I do try to help you there. Here is my recommendation: since you stick to CloudGear, try installing Savanna 0.3 by following this doc:
http://savanna.readthedocs.org/en/0.3/userdoc/installation.guide.html

Follow the path "install into a virtual environment". Make sure you do '.../pip install savanna' and not 'pip install savanna-master'. This should work ok. Then follow this configuration guide:

https://review.openstack.org/#/c/84871/1/doc/source/userdoc/configuration.guide.rst

It is on the review yet and for the Icehouse, but should work for 0.3 as well.

Comment: Ok I followed. It shows 

wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8080/

but no progress at all... no further output

Comment: That is absolutely fine. The server has started and is listening for requests. Now you need to use either Savanna UI or Savanna REST API to use Savanna.

Comment: Now should I install Savanna UI by opening another terminal?

Comment: Yep, I think that would be the easiest way

Comment: Okay let me try this.

Comment: Another question.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/442863/23634-wsgi-starting-up-on-http-0-0-0-08080?noredirect=1#comment579473_442863

Comment: Kindly also see my comments on that question. When I access 0.0.0.0:8080 from browser. It says 'Authentication required'