# (23634) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8080/

Tags: 12.04, openstack

I have followed tutorial to install OpenStack from here

http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/ (http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/set...)

and I tried to install Savanna

When I execute this command

```
savanna-venv/bin/python savanna-venv/bin/savanna-api --config-file savanna-venv/etc/savanna.conf
```

No progress shows and Terminal is stuck and keeps showing this for long time, and does nothing.

```
WARNING keystoneclient.middleware.auth_token [-] Configuring auth_uri to point to the public 
identity endpoint is 
required; clients may not be able to authenticate against an admin endpoint
(23634) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

Comment: What are you expecting? Have you tried accessing that computer on port 8080?

Comment: I think that's how its *supposed* to work.

Comment: @Oli it says    Authentication required

Comment: See from #6 here: http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/install-guide/install/apt/content/neutron-install.dedicated-network-node.html (you might need to do some more configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment as I have too little karma, so I will ask in the answer.

Did you install Savanna UI with the following guide?
http://savanna.readthedocs.org/en/0.3/horizon/installation.guide.html

If yes, you should see a new Savanna tab to appear in your Horizon (OpenStack Dashboard).

Comment: I have not installed yet. I accessed the http://0.0.0.0:8080/ from browser but it said 'Authentication Error'

Comment: Did it showed to you too? Or I should just proceed to install Savavva UI?

Comment: You should proceed with installing Savanna UI. Savanna exposes REST API on port 8080, which you can not access with the browser.

When you install Savanna UI, it will use that port to work with Savanna service.

Comment: I did so... now this error
http://askubuntu.com/questions/442979/httpconnectionpoolhost-openstack-port-35357