# HTTPConnectionPool(host='openstack', port=35357):

Tags: 12.04, openstack

I am getting error when I am trying to access `Savanna Dashboard`

Here is the error from log...

```
24690 WARNING keystoneclient.middleware.auth_token [-] 
Retrying on HTTP connection exception: 
HTTPConnectionPool(host='openstack', port=35357): 
Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>:
[Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

I have `OpenStack` configured at `127.0.0.1:5000` but

Where/In which file do I change that `opsnstack` and `35357`?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, for some reason Horizon tries to reach 'openstack' instead of 127.0.0.1. The easiest way to proceed is to add 'openstack' to /etc/hosts. Here find the line starting with 127.0.0.1 and add 'openstack' to its end. For example:

127.0.0.1   localhost openstack